# Почему переменная типа let не попадает в контекст this и window если создана глобально?

Tags: javascript

Почему переменная типа let не попадает в контекст this и windows если создана глобально?

Изучаю js не понимаю, почему переменные типа let не попадают в контекст и их нельзя вывести через this, соответственно я не могу сделать bind и передать в функцию.

```
var test2=100;
console.log(this.test2);// 100

let test3=100;
console.log(this.test3);// undefinded
```

Comment: Кратко, let/const локальные переменные с ограниченной областью видимости, var создается как глобальная переменная. Более детально тут [Переменная var](https://learn.javascript.ru/var)

Comment: И плюс ко всему this это контекст. 
Проще напрямую обращаться тогда к переменой.

Comment: если переменная let создана в глобальной области видимости,  она будет видна во всех функциях внутри

Comment: @Виктория, Вы видите только то, что хотели бы видеть ;-) Прочитайте внимательно - [Глобальный объект](https://learn.javascript.ru/global-object).